# Angular primeng checkbox group with a reactive form - how can I get all checked values?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, primeng

I have a group of p-checkbox elements (PrimeNg), they all share the name attribute and formControlName attribute. The value of the form control is an array (as it should be), but it "remembers" only the last checkbox clicked.

My TS:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MenuItem } from 'primeng/api';
import {
  FormGroup,
  Validators,
  FormControl,
  FormBuilder,
} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

  searchForm: FormGroup;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.searchForm = this.formBuilder.group({});
    this.searchForm.addControl('selectedCities', new FormControl([]));
  }
}
```

My HTML:

```
<h5>Basic</h5>
<form [formGroup]="searchForm">
  <h5>Multiple</h5>
  <div class="p-field-checkbox">
    <p-checkbox
      name="group1"
      value="New York"
      formControlName="selectedCities"
      inputId="ny"
    ></p-checkbox>
    <label for="ny">New York</label>
  </div>
  <div class="p-field-checkbox">
    <p-checkbox
      name="group1"
      value="San Francisco"
      formControlName="selectedCities"
      inputId="sf"
    ></p-checkbox>
    <label for="sf">San Francisco</label>
  </div>
  <div class="p-field-checkbox">
    <p-checkbox
      name="group1"
      value="Los Angeles"
      formControlName="selectedCities"
      inputId="la"
    ></p-checkbox>
    <label for="la">Los Angeles</label>
  </div>
  <div class="p-field-checkbox">
    <p-checkbox
      name="group1"
      value="Chicago"
      formControlName="selectedCities"
      inputId="ch"
    ></p-checkbox>
    <label for="ch">Chicago</label>
  </div>
</form>

<p *ngFor="let city of searchForm.get('selectedCities').value">{{ city }}</p>
```

My Startblitz project:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-checkbox-demo-23nqc7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 2):

From the [official docs (Model Driven Forms section)](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng-v13-lts/#/checkbox), it proposes to bind the formControl instance instead of the `formControlName` attribute.

```
<!-- Wrong -->
<p-checkbox formControlName="cities"></p-checkbox>

<!-- Correct -->
<p-checkbox [formControl]="myFormGroup.controls['cities']"></p-checkbox>
```

```
<p-checkbox
  name="group1"
  value="New York"
  [formControl]="searchForm.get('selectedCities')"
  inputId="ny"
></p-checkbox>
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-checkbox-demo-9mzmub?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Which documentation should I be using, [https://www.primefaces.org/primeng-v13-lts/#/checkbox](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng-v13-lts/#/checkbox) or [https://primeng.org/checkbox](https://primeng.org/checkbox)?

Comment: Hi, it depends on which PrimeNG version you used. Always follow the instruction provided based on the version you used. From PrimeNG 16, seems like you can use `formControlName` directly compared to v13 which will have the issue.